# Mono custom widget not rendering in designer

Tags: mono, widget, monodevelop, cairo

I have created a custom widget rendering with Cairo and running the app it works as expected, however, in Designer, the widget does not render anything.

Any thoughts?

Code is rather simple:

```
    protected override bool OnExposeEvent (Gdk.EventExpose ev)
    {
        using (Cairo.Context ctx = Gdk.CairoHelper.Create (ev.Window)) {
            DrawBackground (ctx);
            DrawLabel (ctx);
        }
        return base.OnExposeEvent (ev);
    }
```

Yet, when in Designer, the OnExposeEvent is never triggered.

It would really help with layouts and the like if I can get the widget to render in Designer.

Answer (score 0):

The designer doesn't support rendering of custom widgets.

Comment: Really?! I didn't see that mentioned anywhere in the docs!
Would you say I should avoid using the designer in general? (it seems quite unstable)